# Mi login funciona solo la primera vez (php) y no se por que

Tags: php, html, login

Tengo un login.php que se envía los datos a él mismo y los recibe, el problema es que solo me funciona la primera vez y la segunda si lo deja pasar y no entiendo porque. Lo hice en la misma página porque cuando usaba dos no lograba imprimir el alert en la de login.php

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
header('Location: oficial.php');
}
unset ($_SESSION['usuario']);
?>
<form class="form-signin" action="login.php"  method="POST">
            <h1 class="text-center login-title" style="color:black;">Autos Españoles S.A de C.V</h1>
            <h1 class="text-center login-title">Sistema Rom Gerencial</h1>
            <h1 class="text-center login-title">Inicia Sesión</h1>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" id="usuario" name="usuario" required autofocus>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" id="contrasena" name="contrasena" required>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="btn" type="submit">
                Entrar</button>

            <span class="clearfix"></span>                
            </form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
    $usuario = filter_var(strtoupper 
    ($_POST['usuario']),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    # connect to a DSN "mydb" with a user and password 
    $connect = odbc_connect("proyectoSEAT3", "JP", "2246") or die("Error 
    Connect to Database");
    $query = "SELECT nombre, contrasena FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = 
    '$usuario'";
    # perform the query
    $result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);
    # fetch the data from the database
    while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){
        $nombre = odbc_result($result, 1);
        $contra = odbc_result($result, 2);
    }
    # close the connection
    odbc_close($connect);
    if ($usuario == "$nombre" and $contrasena =="$contra") {
        $_SESSION['start'] = time();
        $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (480 * 60);
        header('Location: oficial.php'); 

    }else{  
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("usuario o contraseña incorrecta")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Creo que la variable de `sessión` para `$_SESSION['usuario']` debería crearse dentro del  `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que estas asignando `$usuario` a la variable `session` antes de validar si es correcto o no los datos, ademas esta variable nunca se limpia, por lo tanto

```
if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
header('Location: oficial.php');
}
```

solo la primera ves es falso, luego sera verdadero, ya que, la `session` ya fue definida.
Podrias realizarlo de esta manera:

```
if ($usuario == "$nombre" and $contrasena =="$contra") {
        $_SESSION['start'] = time();
        $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (480 * 60);
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario; //asignamos la session
        header('Location: oficial.php'); 

    }else{ 
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = '';//Limpiamos
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("usuario o contraseña incorrecta")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por responder pero sigue dando acceso la segunda vez :/

Comment: Mentira, tenías razón solo inicialicé la variable $nombre al principio y ya funciona muchas gracias

Comment: y quitaste la asignación de la variable $_SESSION['usuario'] ubicada antes de la conneccion a la bd